# Use $X^{-1}Y$ instead of $(^T)^{−1}^T Y$ to calculate $\beta$ when $X$ is already a square matrix in the least square problem

Tags: regression, linear, matrix-inverse

In the least squares problem $X\beta = Y$, the solution is $\hat{\beta} = (^T)^{−1}^TY$. I learned that two facts:

1. $^T$ is square matrix so that the definition of matrix inversion is satisfied.
2. $(^T)^{-1}$ is related to the variance of the estimated coefficient

But when $X$ is already a square matrix, can I just use this estimator $X^{-1}Y$ to calculate the parameter coefficient $\beta$?

Thanks to @Whuber So the short answer is if $X$ is invertible, then the basic matrix operations work.

Assume $X$ is a 2x2 matrix, how is the effect of the correlation between column 1 (X[,1]) and column 2 (X[,2]) affect the results $X^{-1}Y$?

I guess as long as the correlation is not too severe, the computation of $X^{-1}Y$ is OKay. But when the correlation is too close to 1, the $X^{-1}Y$ result depends on the numerical tolerance in the methods like QR or Cholesky decomposition in a specific softare. Is the thought process correct?

Comment: Hint: if you assume $X$ is invertible (which you seem to do), you can use basic matrix operations to simplify the formula for $\hat\beta.$

Comment: @whuber Thanks much for the quick reply. So the short answer is if $X$ is invertible, then the basic matrix operations work. I added a follow-up question in the post.

Comment: What does your edit mean?  You have agreed the two expressions are the same, so what could possibly "affect the results"?

Comment: @whuber good point, I updated the questions.

Comment: If $X$ is a square matrix, the resulting estimator of $\beta$ is not going to be very good as this is equivalent to estimating the mean of a vector by this vector.

Comment: @Xi'an is it possible to have an example to illustrate the idea? I am not clear about this point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $X$ is invertible then $X^{-1} = (X^\top X)^{-1} X^\top$. You can check this by the definition:

- $(X^\top X)^{-1} X^\top X = I$, so it is the left-inverse of $X$.
- $X(X^\top X)^{-1} X^\top$ is the projection onto the column space of $X$, which is $I$ because $X$ is full rank. So it is a right-inverse as well.
- Alternatively, you might recall that for full-rank matricies, every left-inverse is also a genuine inverse, so it sufficed to stop after the first step.